# Как сделать необязательный параметр в Action Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

Помогите пожалуйста, нужно реализовать выполнение экшена с возможность не заполнения параметра ($url)
чтобы был доступен такой адрес, site/news/, выполняется у меня же экшен только если параметр есть - site/news/parametrurl
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если параметра нет то выскакивает это сообщение об ошибке, можно ли как нибудь сделать параметр не обязательным, чтобы ее не было.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ну например так:

```php
[
    'pattern' => 'posts/<page:\d+>/<tag>',
    'route' => 'post/index',
    'defaults' => ['page' => 1, 'tag' => ''],
]
```

Подставить дефолтные значения в роутере.

Код взял с руководства на  сайте [yiiframework.com](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-routing)

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант установить значение по умолчанию null на уровне действия.
В таком варианте лучше всего установить вместо where - filterWhere. При втором условие будет применяться в случае если $url не пустое. При первом запрос будет соответсвтенно искать значение null.

```
public function actionIndex($url = null)
{
    $model = News::find()
        ->filterWhere(['url' => $url])
        ->one();
    ...
}
```